# Exception when parsing a Ruby expression in JRuby

Tags: java, jruby

I create a String with the content of a ruby file, but when I try to parse it with the JRubyEngine scriptEngine I get a NegativeArraySizeException during the parsing of the expression.

I know its during the yacc parsing of the JRuby engine, but I don't have more information. The code I execute is:

```
rubyEngine = (JRubyEngine) manager.getEngineByName("jruby");
RubyClass klass = (RubyClass) rubyEngine.eval(scriptContent);
```

And I get an exception at the last line. The rb script is:

```
class myRubyObject
require org.scripthelper.ruby.samples.Script
  def execute() {
    10
  }
end
```

The Script class is a java class which has only the following method:

```
public int execute();
```

I expected to get a RubyClass, but instead I get this NegativeArraySizeException during parsing.

Here is the stack trace of the exception:

```
    at org.jruby.embed.jsr223.JRubyEngine.wrapException(JRubyEngine.java:104)
    at org.jruby.embed.jsr223.JRubyEngine.eval(JRubyEngine.java:93)
    at org.jruby.embed.jsr223.JRubyEngine.eval(JRubyEngine.java:142)
...
Caused by: org.jruby.embed.ParseFailedException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.runParser(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:207)
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:94)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.parse(ScriptingContainer.java:1227)
    at org.jruby.embed.jsr223.JRubyEngine.eval(JRubyEngine.java:89)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.SyntaxException.prepareMessage(SyntaxException.java:111)
    at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.SyntaxException.<init>(SyntaxException.java:96)
    at org.jruby.lexer.yacc.RubyLexer.compile_error(RubyLexer.java:390)
    at org.jruby.parser.ParserSupport.yyerror(ParserSupport.java:1200)
    at org.jruby.parser.RubyParser$116.execute(RubyParser.java:2541)
    at org.jruby.parser.RubyParser.yyparse(RubyParser.java:1698)
    at org.jruby.parser.RubyParser.yyparse(RubyParser.java:1589)
    at org.jruby.parser.RubyParser.parse(RubyParser.java:5744)
    at org.jruby.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:133)
    at org.jruby.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:87)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.parseEval(Ruby.java:2729)
```

Comment: Please also add the exception stacktrace.

Comment: Hello please upload the full output of the program in order to give you better help

Comment: Hello, I added the Stack trace in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can post an answer again. The correct script was:

```
require 'java'
class MyRubyObject
java_implements org.scripthelper.ruby.samples.Script
  def execute()
    return 10
  end
end
```

The errors I made before were:

- The def methods should not be enclosed by {}
- The require 'java' before the content should be important
- I did not correctly define that the org.scripthelper.ruby.samples.Script class was implemented by the Ruby class
- Also the name of a Ruby class must have its first character in capitals

The Java code was correct:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
JRubyEngine rubyEngine = (JRubyEngine) manager.getEngineByName("jruby");
rubyEngine.eval(scriptContent);

RubyObject object = (RubyObject) rubyEngine.eval(className + ".new");
Script s = object.toJava(Script.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The scriptContent must have some error related to NegativeArraySizeException

check the script, or  test with another script failure proof, for example

```
> rubyEngine = (JRubyEngine) manager.getEngineByName("jruby"); RubyClass
> rubyEngine.eval("puts('hello world')");
```

Comment: I understood my problem. A few things were incorrect. However I'm not able to asnwer to my own question which is a shame. in short (without code because I can't post it): the brackets are wrong, the class name should begin with an upper case, and the way to declare that the class implements a Java class was incorrect.

Comment: Glad to know I help :D